# Sum of combined elements from a file

Tags: python, list, text

I'm pretty new to Python and I'm stuck in building the logic for my program. I want to learn, but I feel I need some external help. Maybe you guys can help me. This is Homework/Project.

The `list (SalesData.txt)` looks like this:

- Name 1
- 23
- 34
- 454
- Name 2
- 344
- 34
- 45

And it continues for at least 5 different names. But for the example, this will do.

Basically, I need to come up with a TOTAL of all the numbers and then, a total for every name.

**Output** :: In this case (using example)

1. Grand Total = 934 (sum of all the numbers)
2. Name 1 Total = 511 (sum of numbers for Name 1)
3. Name 2 Total = 423 (sum of numbers for Name 2)

I know how to get a total sum of a file containing ONLY numbers, but when it comes to a mixture I'm very confused. Also, how can I specified in getting the Total of every single `"name"`. should I use the `.isdigit()` and `.isalpha()` to tell the list when to sum and when to not sum?

Any advise will help me! thanks!

**UPDATE**
This is my code so far:

```
data = []
data = open("SalesData.txt").read().split()
    for i in data:
        s = sum([ float(i) ])
print "Sum=" , s
print "Avg="  , s/len(data)
```

This only works if the file is all NUMBERS, that's pretty easy to sum the contents.but remember, I'm dealing with a String every 12 numbers. I'm trying to figure how to just do the sum only when it finds a line with a float.

**Update #2**

I would still like some guidance! I'm beginning to wrap things up in my own way, but I find some very basic trouble (I'm sure)

```
data = []
data = open("SalesData.txt").read().split()
    for i in data:
        if str(i):
            print 'This one is Letter'
        elif float(i):
            s = sum([ float(i) ])
print "Sum=" , s
print "Avg="  , s/len(data)
```

I know this example doesn't work and I want to know why. I'm trying to analyze the list. 
IF 'i' is a string, the program will (in this example print 'Letter') if it's not a string, it will do the regular sum of numbers. I'm taking this program one piece at the time, I want to be able to get a total sum of numbers using the mixed provided list, but I'm stuck in the aspect of analyzing the strings as strings and floats as floats.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `.isdigit()` will return `False` if you have a non-integer or negative value (e.g. 342.2 or -342), so that may not be a good mechanism to use.

As Kreativitea noted, `int()` may be used to discern words from numbers (integers, specifically), but consider that `float()` would work in the more general case when the numbers may be integer or floating point.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about .isdigit() returning a FALSE when used in floats (343.2). All my numbers have decimals, so another way is necessary. 
I'm sorry to have to ask, this being homework, but I've never used int() to discern between types of data, an example will help me out! If possible

Comment: The proper way to test, in Python, is to use exception handling; EAFP.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is homework, I will just give general guidelines.

1. You don't need to use isdigit or isalpha.  What happens when you try to use an `int()` on something that isn't an integer? Okay, now you have a process that discerns between the two groups.
2. Will the list of numbers always have the same number of items after it?  If not, a `while` loop might be a good idea.
3. In either case, what quality does the data have, as in, describe the data in abstract terms.  What data structures maps well to that kind of data?
4. Break up the process; it's better to create two functions that are easy to read than one function that's difficult to read.

Good luck. :)

Comment: Thank you!
1. Thanks! It makes sense
2. Yes, it contains :: 'Name' and then 12 rows (representing each month of the year) with float numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the names are unique, you can fill a [dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) from the file so that keys are names and values are lists of numbers. Then it'll be easy to get `sum` for each item and also a `sum` of sums.

To build a dict, you need to put together a simple parser. For instance:

```
def parse(fname):
    data = {}
    numbers = []
    for line in f:
       # figure out if line has name or number
       if ... # this is a number
           numbers.append(float(line))
       else:
           data[name] = numbers
    return data
```

This is not full code, because it's a homework question. Also note that you probably need to correctly take care of the very first name you read on the first line.

Comment: Even if the names are unique in the project, I would like to be able to input another file, with same quantity of data but different names and numbers (keeping the same format).
+ I'm not very familiar with the dict function, can you elaborate? I'm sorry -- I'm having a lot of difficulty

Answer (score 0):

Regarding update #2: there are several logical problems here.

First off, `if str(i):` does not mean "if `i` is a string, ...". It means "create a string from `i`; now, if the resulting string is non-empty, ...".

Second, `i` comes from `data`, which is a list of lines of the file. So it **must** be a string. That's what you get when you read a file. No attempt is made to interpret the various symbols as numbers until *you tell the program to*.

Third, when such a conversion fails, it will fail by raising an exception. You cannot test for that with an `if` block. You must use `try`/`except` exception handling.

Fourth, you are trying to calculate `s` every time you get a number, using a one element list with just that number. That's not going to give you a sum of all the numbers. If you wan to sum several numbers, you have to put the numbers together somewhere first.

Fifth, you use `len(data)` as the count of numbers to divide the sum by. This is wrong since that is the number of lines in your file, and you've already said that some of them might be excluded. You want to count up just the numbers, which again requires putting that list together first.

Write something that can give you the list of numbers first, and then it is a simple matter of using `sum` and `len` with that list (once each, outside of the loop).